# Return first outer result from a string, using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
"{My {formatted {hi|hello}|formate{hi|hello} }  {option 1|option 2|option 3}}";
```

I want find the result in-between the "{"  and "}" brackets.

Also result should be from the outer layer, not `{hi|hello}` but:

```
"My {formatted {hi|hello}|formate{hi|hello} }  {option 1|option 2|option 3}"
```

Comment: So you want to remove the outer `{}`? why not: `$str = substr($str,1,-1);`?

Comment: Just strip off the braces; no?

Comment: If u make your regex greedy he will take the first and last occurrence

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Why do you think that regular expressions are the right tool for this particular job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/^{(.*)}$/` would remove the first and last `{` and `}`

used via `$var = preg_replace('/^{(.*)}$/', '$1', $your_text);`

That particularly can be made with basic string operations too, you could advance that regex to `/^[^{]*{(.*)}[^{]*$/` which would let you put chars in front of the desired string and after it. Again, this can be done with string operations itself, using `substr` and `strrpos`.

Answer (score 6):

You can extract the most outer content from an indeterminate level number of nested brackets with this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~{((?>[^{}]++|(?R))+)}~';
```

where `(?R)` means *repeat the whole pattern*. It is a recursive approach.
If you need the same to use as subpattern in a larger expression, you must use:
 `({((?>[^{}]++|(?-2))+)})` since the `(?-2)` is a relative reference to the second capturing group on the left (the first here).

Pattern details:

```
 (             # first capturing group
   {           # literal {
   (           # second capturing group (what you are looking for)
     (?>       # atomic group
       [^{}]++ # all characters except { and }, one or more time
      |        # OR
       (?-2)   # repeat the first capturing group (second on the left)
     )+        # close the atomic group, repeated 1 or more time
   )           # close the second capturing group
   }           # literal }
 )             # close the first capturing group
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the **split** Function.E then you can use the **Replace**.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.split.php